# Spring REST webservice and session persistence

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-session

I have this Spring webservice test code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/counter")
public class CounterController
{       
    @Autowired
    private Counter counter;    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/inc", method = GET)   
    public int inc() throws Exception {                     
        counter.incCounter();
        return counter.getCounter();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = GET)   
    public int get() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        return counter.getCounter();                
    }

}
```

where Counter is a session scoped object

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Counter implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9162936878293396831L;

    private int value;
    public int getCounter() {
        return value;
        }
    public void incCounter() {
        value += 1;
    }
}
```

The session configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds=1800)
public class HttpSessionConfig {    
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }    
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy(){
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
}
```

As you can see the `get()` method sleeps 5 secons and returns the value of the counter.
The problem is that if I call `inc()` many times during the execution of the `get()` all the counter changes are lost because when `get()` finishes returns the value of the counter that it has when started the execution. The weird problem is that `get()` when finishes persists the counter (It is a session object) and when this operation is done all the changes are lost. 
Does exist a way to prevent that functions that do not modify a session object not persist it?

Update: I think that the Spring code corroborates this wrong behavior. This snippet of code of the class `ServletRequestAttributes` shows that every session object that is accessed (regardless if the access is for read) is marked to be saved when the webservice operation finishes:

```
@Override
    public Object getAttribute(String name, int scope) {
        if (scope == SCOPE_REQUEST) {
            if (!isRequestActive()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore!");
            }
            return this.request.getAttribute(name);
        }
        else {
            HttpSession session = getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                try {
                    Object value = session.getAttribute(name);
                    if (value != null) {
                        this.sessionAttributesToUpdate.put(name, value);
                    }
                    return value;
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // Session invalidated - shouldn't usually happen.
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

According to the Spring Session documentation:

> Optimized Writes
>
> The Session instances managed by RedisOperationsSessionRepository
>   keeps track of the properties that have changed and only updates
>   those. This means if an attribute is written once and read many times
>   we only need to write that attribute once.

Or the documentation is wrong or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: any particular reason why `Counter` can't be singleton / non-session scoped ?

Comment: Do you have proper configuration in web.xml to enable session scope?

Comment: This listener must be added in web.xml org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener

Comment: It is session scoped and it is session scoped because I want to learn to use the session scope on concurrent environments properly

Comment: So the requests come in different sessions? Your service is not a REST service btw. and `inc()` must not be called with `GET`, because `GET` calls must not have side-effects.

Comment: Same session. Every session has its own Counter object saved on a Redis database. It is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is nothing to do with this problem, this is the expected behavior of Spring Session with session scoped beans. For me it 's a critical problem and I've decided forget distributed caches (`Redis` and `Hazelcast`) and use the `MapSessionRepository`

Answer (score 1):

I think You did some mistakes while testing Your code. I have just tested it, **and it works as expected.**

I have used SoapUI, created 2 request's with the same `JSESSIONID` value in Cookie (same session).

Then I requested for /get, and meanwhile in second request window, i spammed /inc.

What /get returned was the number of /inc. (at the beggining value was 0 , than I have incremented it to 11 while /get was sleeping. Finally, /get returned 11).

I suggest You double check if nothing is messed up with Your session.

Edit: Your code with additional logs: (I've increased the sleeping time to 10000):

```
2016-04-06 11:56:10.977  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 14 ms
2016-04-06 11:56:11.014  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Before 10sec counter value: 0
2016-04-06 11:56:21.015  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : After 10sec counter value: 0
2016-04-06 11:56:36.955  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Before 10sec counter value: 0
2016-04-06 11:56:46.956  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : After 10sec counter value: 0
2016-04-06 11:56:50.558  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 1
2016-04-06 11:56:53.494  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Before 10sec counter value: 1
2016-04-06 11:57:03.496  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : After 10sec counter value: 1
2016-04-06 11:57:05.600  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Before 10sec counter value: 1
2016-04-06 11:57:06.715  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 2
2016-04-06 11:57:06.869  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 3
2016-04-06 11:57:07.038  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 4
2016-04-06 11:57:07.186  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 5
2016-04-06 11:57:07.321  INFO 7884 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 6
2016-04-06 11:57:07.478  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 7
2016-04-06 11:57:07.641  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 8
2016-04-06 11:57:07.794  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 9
2016-04-06 11:57:07.967  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 10
2016-04-06 11:57:08.121  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : Incrementing counter value: 11
2016-04-06 11:57:15.602  INFO 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.p.controller.TestServiceController     : After 10sec counter value: 11
```

Comment: The problems are not in testing. I'm using Spring session with Redis. Maybe my mistakes are in the Redis configuration

Comment: Than its as You said in Redis, as the code that You provided as an example, is working.

Comment: I didn't, Your question didn't mention anything connected with Redis before. I've just checked the Spring session-scope behavior.

Comment: Can you show me your session configuration files? How do you configure the session scope?

Comment: I did that in Spring Boot, so no additional configuration. But in classic Spring You have to add: 

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener> to Your web.xml file. Someone already mentioned that in previous comment I think

Comment: If You use Spring Boot, or classic Spring with listener added to web.xml, @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) does the whole work.

Comment: The sessions works fine but I have the concurrence problem. I do not configure using xml I use annotations. I put the Session configuration on the question

Comment: When working with annotations, register the RequestContextListener bean : @Bean public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
}

Comment: Than in my opinion it's not a Spring problem.